# How to get all of the IP addresses in a string into a bash array

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, ip-address

I have the following string:

```
redis. 600 IN A 172.16.0.3 redis. 600 IN A 172.16.0.4 redis. 600 IN A 172.16.0.5 redis. 600 IN A 172.16.0.6 redis. 600 IN A 172.16.0.7
```

The string is obtained from the following command:

```
dig redis A | grep redis | grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

The string is printed out on each line when the command is run, but I save the output to a variable so it's all one line. I want to get all of the IP addresses into a bash array. What's the best way for me to do this?

**Edit:** This post is not a duplicate because the focus of this was how to get the IP addresses, not how to read them into the array.

Comment: If you show the file after dig command and add awk in the tag of your question, I'm sure you get a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up being able to do it by using awk:

```
IPAddresses=($(dig redis A | grep redis | grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | awk '{print $5}'))
```

The IPAddresses array has all of the IP addresses in it, and can be printed out by executing `echo "${IPAddresses[@]}"`